# clever way to add nested properties?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const data = { 
  "orders" : [ 
    { "items" : {"count":3} },  
    { "items" : {"count":1} },  
    { "items" : {"count":2} } 
  ]
}
let total = 0
data.orders.map((order) => order.items.map((item) => (total += item.count)))
console.log(total)
```

Is there a more clever way to do that, where I could say `console.log(someoperation(data))` ?

Comment: You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: `order.items` is not an array, you can't `.map()` it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have works, but you can also use the array `.reduce` method:

```js
const data = { 
  "orders" : [ 
    { "items" : {"count":3} },  
    { "items" : {"count":1} },  
    { "items" : {"count":2} } 
  ]
}

const total = data.orders.reduce((cnt, item) => { return cnt+item.items.count; }, 0)

console.log(total)
```

EDIT:

Also, if you have lodash, this is even easier:

```
const total = _.sumBy(data.orders, x => x.items.count); // evaluates to 6
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nested [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the value for counting.

```js
var data = { orders: [{ items: { count: 3 } }, { items: { count: 1 } }, { items: { count: 2 } }] },
    total = data.orders.reduce((s, { items: { count } }) => s + count, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Function for a single call with the object

```js
const getCount = ({ orders }) => orders.reduce((s, { items: { count } }) => s + count, 0);

var data = { orders: [{ items: { count: 3 } }, { items: { count: 1 } }, { items: { count: 2 } }] };

console.log(getCount(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it in a function with params:

```
function getTotal(startVal) {
  var total = startVal;
  data.orders.map((order) => order.items.map((item) => (total += item.count)))  
  const data = { 
    "orders" : [ 
      { "items" : {"count":3} },  
      { "items" : {"count":1} },  
      { "items" : {"count":2} } 
    ]
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(getTotals(0));
```

Comment: The function should take an argument, not hard-code the global variable name.